# Find Minimum without Zero and NaN in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan, zero

I have a pandas Dataframe and I want to find the minimum without zeros and Nans.
I was trying to combine from numpy nonzero and nanmin, but it does not work.

Does someone has an idea?

Comment: Can you add some data sample?

Comment: Just filter first and get the min

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want the minimum of all df, you can try so:

```
m = np.nanmin(df.replace(0, np.nan).values)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with [`numpy.nanmin`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmin.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'B':[4,0,4,5,5,np.nan],
                   'C':[7,8,9,np.nan,2,3],
                   'D':[1,np.nan,5,7,1,0],
                   'E':[5,3,0,9,2,4]})

print (df)
     B    C    D  E
0  4.0  7.0  1.0  5
1  0.0  8.0  NaN  3
2  4.0  9.0  5.0  0
3  5.0  NaN  7.0  9
4  5.0  2.0  1.0  2
5  NaN  3.0  0.0  4
```

Numpy solution:

```
arr = df.values
a = np.nanmin(np.where(arr == 0, np.nan, arr))
print (a)
1.0
```

Pandas solution - `NaN`s are removed by default:

```
a = df.mask(df==0).min().min()
print (a)
1.0
```

**Performance** - for each row is added one `NaN` value:

```
np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(1000,1000))
np.fill_diagonal(df.values, np.nan)
print (df)

#joe answer
In [399]: %timeit np.nanmin(df.replace(0, np.nan).values)
15.3 ms ± 425 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [400]: %%timeit 
     ...: arr = df.values
     ...: a = np.nanmin(np.where(arr == 0, np.nan, arr))
     ...: 
6.41 ms ± 427 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [401]: %%timeit
     ...: df.mask(df==0).min().min()
     ...: 
23.9 ms ± 727 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```